# how to validate two dropdowns depends upon selection?

Tags: angular10

I have two Dropdowns first dropdown 1 to 23 hours and the second dropdown also 1 to 23 hours.
If I select the first Dropdown is 4.the second drop-down is higher than the first dropdown selected value. how to do that

Comment: share your code

Comment: First of all Thank you for Response.

Comment: First Dropdown 1 to 23 numbers. and the second dropdown also the same if I select the first drop down is any selected number and the second dropdown is automatically enable the greater then first value. and we can show the message like please select the highest value.

Comment: so you can set 1st  dropdown  selected value in 2nd dropdown .

Comment: Are you getting my answer? Please atleast give the reply

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for your concern. I have used the form if you are not used form then remove it and take the normal angular control.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select formControlName="firstDropdown" class="form-control" (change)="firstDropDownChange($event)">
          <option *ngFor="let value of values" [value]="value">
            <span>{{ value }}</span>
          </option>
        </select>
        <select formControlName="secondDropdown" class="form-control" (change)="secondDropDownChange($event)">
          <option *ngFor="let value of values1" [value]="value">
            <span>{{ value }}</span>
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">
        Submit
      </button>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
values: any = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];
values1: any = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];
firstDropdown: any = 1;
secondDropdown: any = 1;
form: FormGroup;

constructor() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstDropdown: new FormControl(1),
      secondDropdown: new FormControl(1),
    });
}



  firstDropDownChange(event) {
    this.values1 = this.values.filter(
      (data) => parseInt(event.target.value) <= data
    );
    console.log(this.values1);
    this.form.controls['secondDropdown'].setValue(parseInt(this.values1[0]));
  }

  secondDropDownChange(event) {}

  submit() {}
```

Comment: Are you getting the answere?