# How can I show cities depending on selected country in angular

Tags: angular, dropdown, html-select

Friends. Can someone guide me on how I can do cascade type dropdown? showing the cities  depending on the selected country, Since the request for the city brings me about 3,000 cities but I want to show only the cities  of the selected country
This is the structure of the country:

````
"idCountryOfResidence": "a15c81c7-aac1-40c1-bb2c-1925b2a3f765",
      "code": "CO",
      "name": "COLOMBIA",
      "description": "COLOMBIA"
}```
and this is the structure of the city
```Data:{
"idCity": "8235e138-33e3-4eae-b16e-2b10faa4d1ff",
      "code1": "C001",
      "code2": "CO",
      "name": "BEEJORRAL",
      "description": "BEEJORRAL",
      "code4": "CO01"
}```
For example, the "code" property in country is the same as the "code2" property in city, filtering could be done there, but I haven't achieved it yet.
Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

I have already given answer. Same functionality you can use in your code. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66365004/8213994) answere. In this answer two dropdown's are there and second dropdown is depend on first dropdown. You can put your condition based on your requirement.

Comment: If you don't understanding the code then share your data with me I will created the demo using your data.